# Differentiate Back/Forward click and History.pushState/replaceState in statechange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I am using History.js plugin which support HTML 5 pushState and replaceState. The statechange is triggered when a user click back/forward button and when pushState/replaceState is used. I need to check whether statechange event is triggered from back/forward button or by using  pushState/replaceState methods.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at History.js, but [Ben Alman's jQuery BBQ (Back-Button & Queue Library)](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) is an excellent library that contains a 'hashchange' event.  This might be different than what you are trying to do, though, since his library relies on hashtags in a URL, and not a browser's internal statechange.  [He's also got a repo on GitHub for hashchange](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange).

Answer (score 1):

According to a discussion on the GitHub by the author, it is impossible to do that (from a year ago, can't find the link again).
Your option really is to look for some kind of a workaround like breadcrumbs etc.

Comment: Did you ever find that link? I think it was possible even in 2011. See for example the code I gave in answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255).