# How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, back

How do you definitively detect whether or not the user has pressed the back button in the browser?

How do you enforce the use of an in-page back button inside a single page web application using a `#URL` system?

Why on earth don't browser back buttons fire their own events!?

Comment: I wish navigation events (backward/forward) get added sometime. So far this is something being in works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming

Comment: Please support this proposal for the `ongoback` event: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/set-back-button-url-in-pwas/4112

Comment: Is it possible that these buttons don't allow interception since that would allow an app to "lock" the browser on a page?

Comment: 300 upvote and not a single working answer yet

Comment: @greendino - the issue related to the API himself (No explanation why popstate not store the directions - move back VS forward). Shitty like Hell. All the answers here dedect "both" events (back and forward). `no answer yet`  (hh +9 years later)

Answer (score 251, accepted):

(Note: As per Sharky's feedback, I've included code to detect backspaces)

So, I've seen these questions frequently on SO, and have recently run into the issue of controlling back button functionality myself. After a few days of searching for the best solution for my application (Single-Page with Hash Navigation), I've come up with a simple, cross-browser, library-less system for detecting the back button.

Most people recommend using:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
 //blah blah blah
}
```

However, this function will also be called when a user uses on in-page element that changes the location hash. Not the best user experience when your user clicks and the page goes backwards or forwards.

To give you a general outline of my system, I'm filling up an array with previous hashes as my user moves through the interface. It looks something like this:

```
function updateHistory(curr) {
    window.location.lasthash.push(window.location.hash);
    window.location.hash = curr;
}
```

Pretty straight forward. I do this to ensure cross-browser support, as well as support for older browsers. Simply pass the new hash to the function, and it'll store it for you and then change the hash (which is then put into the browser's history).

I also utilise an in-page back button that moves the user between pages using the `lasthash` array. It looks like this:

```
function goBack() {
    window.location.hash = window.location.lasthash[window.location.lasthash.length-1];
    //blah blah blah
    window.location.lasthash.pop();
}
```

So this will move the user back to the last hash, and remove that last hash from the array (I have no forward button right now).

So. How do I detect whether or not a user has used my in-page back button, or the browser button?

At first I looked at `window.onbeforeunload`, but to no avail - that is only called if the user is going to change pages. This does not happen in a single-page-application using hash navigation.

So, after some more digging, I saw recommendations for trying to set a flag variable. The issue with this in my case, is that I would try to set it, but as everything is asynchronous, it wouldn't always be set in time for the if statement in the hash change. `.onMouseDown` wasn't always called in click, and adding it to an onclick wouldn't ever trigger it fast enough.

This is when I started to look at the difference between `document`, and `window`. My final solution was to set the flag using `document.onmouseover`, and disable it using `document.onmouseleave`.

What happens is that while the user's mouse is inside the document area (read: the rendered page, but excluding the browser frame), my boolean is set to `true`. As soon as the mouse leaves the document area, the boolean flips to `false`.

This way, I can change my `window.onhashchange` to:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
        window.innerDocClick = false;
    } else {
        if (window.location.hash != '#undefined') {
            goBack();
        } else {
            history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll note the check for `#undefined`. This is because if there is no history available in my array, it returns `undefined`. I use this to ask the user if they want to leave using a `window.onbeforeunload` event.

So, in short, and for people that aren't necessarily using an in-page back button or an array to store the history:

```
document.onmouseover = function() {
    //User's mouse is inside the page.
    window.innerDocClick = true;
}

document.onmouseleave = function() {
    //User's mouse has left the page.
    window.innerDocClick = false;
}

window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
        //Your own in-page mechanism triggered the hash change
    } else {
        //Browser back button was clicked
    }
}
```

And there you have it. a simple, three-part way to detect back button usage vs in-page elements with regards to hash navigation.

EDIT:

To ensure that the user doesn't use backspace to trigger the back event, you can also include the following (Thanks to @thetoolman on [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back)):

```
$(function(){
    /*
     * this swallows backspace keys on any non-input element.
     * stops backspace -> back
     */
    var rx = /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i;

    $(document).bind("keydown keypress", function(e){
        if( e.which == 8 ){ // 8 == backspace
            if(!rx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly ){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 nice idea, but i think this will fail if user uses whatever keyboard shortcut is for "back" (backspace key on firefox) whilst his mouse is inside browser window

Comment: Agreed, but you can intercept the onkey event and check for backspace anyways. The issue has always been detecting the click of the back button. :)

Comment: you should implement this too, its a pity to leave it like this :D

Comment: Will do - I'm in the office right now anyways :) (EDIT: Done now)

Comment: What about mobile (e.g. ipad)

Comment: @basarat - I haven't tested on an iPad or other mobile devices - but given how there are no mouse events on touch devices - I don't believe this is mobile friendly - though I'll spend some time looking into a way to adapt it. :)

Comment: What about swipe events from trackpad in MAC. Could that be captured as well?

Comment: @SriganeshNavaneethakrishnan - I'll need to look into that as well, but I don't have a trackpad or mac at my disposal.

Comment: How can I differentiate forward and backward buttons?

Comment: UPDATE: `window.onhashchange` is **not called** in latest Chrome (69) when I click _back_ button.

Comment: UPDATE: Tom, it is called in Chrome (72) but ONLY if you arrive at that page/hash from another page/hash (maybe the same in 69?). If you hit reload and then press the back button it is NOT called. The same is true for popstate. If anyone finds a solution to catching the back button immediately after a reload then please let me know. :)

Comment: `document.onmouseleave` does not work in FireFox (ver 69. but did in Safari and Chrome). Nor does `document.addEventListener('mouseleave', ....`. Instead I opted for `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', ...` Not as pretty yet does the trick.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect See a possible solution here if you want both forward and back buttons:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102502/preventing-mouse-fourth-and-fifth-buttons-from-navigating-back-forward-in-browse/62482736#62482736

Comment: Is there a way to tell if user pressed cancel or leave page

Comment: what is the difference to the popstate event and are there even more possible options that are not onpageleave and unload?

Answer (score 151):

You can try [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) event handler, e.g:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    // The popstate event is fired each time when the current history entry changes.

    var r = confirm("You pressed a Back button! Are you sure?!");

    if (r == true) {
        // Call Back button programmatically as per user confirmation.
        history.back();
        // Uncomment below line to redirect to the previous page instead.
        // window.location = document.referrer // Note: IE11 is not supporting this.
    } else {
        // Stay on the current page.
        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    }

    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);

}, false);
```

<sup>Note: For the best results, you should load this code only on specific pages where you want to implement the logic to avoid any other unexpected issues.</sup>

The popstate event is fired each time when the current history entry changes (user navigates to a new state). That happens when user clicks on browser's Back/Forward buttons or when `history.back()`, `history.forward()`, `history.go()` methods are programatically called.

The `event.state` is property of the event is equal to the history state object.

For jQuery syntax, wrap it around (to add even listener after document is ready):

```
(function($) {
  // Above code here.
})(jQuery);
```

See also: [window.onpopstate on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15896434/55075)

---

See also the examples on [Single-Page Apps and HTML5 pushState](http://zinoui.com/blog/single-page-apps-html5-pushstate) page:

```
<script>
// jQuery
$(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
    var state = e.originalEvent.state;
    if (state !== null) {
        //load content with ajax
    }
});

// Vanilla javascript
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
    var state = e.state;
    if (state !== null) {
        //load content with ajax
    }
});
</script>
```

This should be compatible with Chrome 5+, Firefox 4+, IE 10+, Safari 6+, Opera 11.5+ and similar.

Comment: Kenorb, you're correct that popstate works to grab the change, but it doesn't differentiate between programmatically calling the event and when the user clicks the browser's buttons.

Comment: Great post on [Single-Page Apps and HTML5 pushState](http://zinoui.com/blog/single-page-apps-html5-pushstate). Perfect for modern "one page layouts" or "single page apps". Thank you for the link and your answer!

Comment: e.state seem always undefined in modern browsers

Comment: I suggest that you put your code in a snippet so that you can run it directly here.

Comment: The popstate event is only triggered by performing a browser action, such as clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript), when navigating between two history entries for the same document.
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate )

Comment: `popstate` event doesn't fire on Back button push.

Comment: The event only fires if user interacts with the page (clicking something). Also as @pref pointed, it won't work when navigating between two pages so you can add this line before the event listener `history.pushState(null, null)`

Answer (score 35):

```
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
  alert('hello world');
}
```

This is the only one solution that worked for me (it's not a onepage website).
It's working with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: window.performance.navigation has been deprecated. Here are the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation

Comment: This worked for me on my .cshtml page. Worked successfully on Chrome and IE. Thanks

Comment: @llaaalu 


This works after the deprecation, I'm not sure about cross browser compatibility:  if (String(window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type) === "back_forward") { // do your code here }

Comment: Oh my gosh! I was trying a lot of variants but only your solution is working!!!  Thank you! You save me after 3 hours of working!

Comment: This is the only solution that works!!! `popstate` event (previous solutions) doesn't fire on Back button push.

Answer (score 25):

I had been struggling with this requirement for quite a while and took some of the solutions above to implement it. However, I stumbled upon an observation and it seems to work across Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers + Android and iPhone

On page load:

```
window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "");

window.onpopstate = function(event) {

  // "event" object seems to contain value only when the back button is clicked
  // and if the pop state event fires due to clicks on a button
  // or a link it comes up as "undefined" 

  if(event){
    // Code to handle back button or prevent from navigation
  }
  else{
    // Continue user action through link or button
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps. If am missing something, I will be happy to understand.

Comment: Not true. `event` has value even for the forward button

Answer (score 24):

Correct answer is already there to answer the question. I want to mention new JavaScript API [PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming), it's replacing deprecated [performance.navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation).

Following code will log in console "back_forward" if user landed on your page using back or forward button. *[Take a look at compatibility table before using it in your project.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type#Browser_compatibility)*

```
var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
for (var i = 0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
    console.log(perfEntries[i].type);
}
```

Comment: This is not a way to tell if a back button *is clicked on this page*.  It tells if it *was clicked on the last page*.

Comment: But it happened to be the actual answer I was looking for since the issue I get is after I hit the back button and not before meaning I can build in some response code that stops my duplicate requests issues. Thanks.

Comment: This may not answer the question, but exactly what I needed! Nice one - I did not know of this...

Answer (score 22):

In javascript, navigation type `2` means browser's back or forward button clicked and the browser is actually taking content from cache.

```
if(performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    //Do your code here
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on a single page application, the result is always 1 (which means reload). Moreover it doesn't make the difference between back and forward button, which is very unfortunate.

Comment: " Moreover it doesn't make the difference between back and forward button, which is very unfortunate. "
yes because whenever data is fetched from cache that time the performance.navigation.type is 2

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work in all browsers! so you should write something like this : 
if(window.performance){
// your performance related code
}
also it's better to use TYPE_BACK_FORWARD instead of 2 for more readability.

Comment: ... and this is now deprecated. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation

Comment: @MisterVanderbilt as this is deprecated, what would be the new alternative code. This solution is so simple, would like to use it

Comment: This works after the deprecation, I'm not sure about cross browser compatibility:  if (String(window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type) === "back_forward") { // do your code here }

Comment: I don't care. It works for me, is good! Dec 2020

Comment: deprecated !! read this for more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type

Answer (score 16):

My variant:

```
const isVisitedViaBackButton = performance && performance.getEntriesByType( 'navigation' ).map( nav => nav.type ).includes( 'back_forward' )
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Comment: To the top with you, the best answer on the page. @return bool true || false

Comment: this is always returning false, doesnt work.

Answer (score 15):

This will definitely work (For detecting back button click)

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
 alert("pop");
});
```

Comment: Best and quickest answer!

Comment: Just that code by itself is not working.

Comment: @rohan parab, brave of you saying "definitely", doesnt work on my chrome

Answer (score 7):

See this:

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
    };
```

it works fine...

Comment: Does not work in Chrome 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Confirmed working on Brave v1.3.118 >> Chromium: 80.0.3987.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Doesn't work if you came on the page from an external site.

Answer (score 6):

Browser: https://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/axt1Lqoz/

For mobile control: https://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/axt1Lqoz/show/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click touch', '#share', function(e) {
    $('.share').fadeIn();
  });
});

// geri butonunu yakalama
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'share') {
    $('.share').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  //console.log('old:'+oldURL+' new:'+newURL);
}
```

```css
.share{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,.8); color:white; padding:20px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Back Button Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="text-align:center; padding:0;">
    <a href="#share" id="share">Share</a>
    <div class="share" style="">
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <p> Back button press please for control.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. The question is about detecting the use of an in-page back button vs the browser's native back button.

Comment: Question is tagged javascript, not jquery.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to use some of the answers in this thread and others to get it working in IE and Chrome/Edge. *history.pushState* for me wasn't supported in IE11.

```
if (history.pushState) {
    //Chrome and modern browsers
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
        history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    });
}
else {
    //IE
    history.forward();
}
```

Comment: Just tried that on Chrome 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

A full-fledged component can be implemented only if you redefine the API (change the methods of object ' history ')
I will share the class just written.
Tested on Chrome and Mozilla
Support only HTML5 and ECMAScript5-6

````
class HistoryNavigation {
    static init()
    {
        if(HistoryNavigation.is_init===true){
            return;
        }
        HistoryNavigation.is_init=true;

        let history_stack=[];
        let n=0;
        let  current_state={timestamp:Date.now()+n};
        n++;
        let init_HNState;
        if(history.state!==null){
            current_state=history.state.HNState;
            history_stack=history.state.HNState.history_stack;
            init_HNState=history.state.HNState;
        } else {
            init_HNState={timestamp:current_state.timestamp,history_stack};
        }
        let listenerPushState=function(params){
            params=Object.assign({state:null},params);
            params.state=params.state!==null?Object.assign({},params.state):{};
            let h_state={ timestamp:Date.now()+n};
            n++;
            let key = history_stack.indexOf(current_state.timestamp);
            key=key+1;
            history_stack.splice(key);
            history_stack.push(h_state.timestamp);
            h_state.history_stack=history_stack;
            params.state.HNState=h_state;
            current_state=h_state;
            return params;
        };
        let listenerReplaceState=function(params){
            params=Object.assign({state:null},params);
            params.state=params.state!==null?Object.assign({},params.state):null;
            let h_state=Object.assign({},current_state);
            h_state.history_stack=history_stack;
            params.state.HNState=h_state;
            return params;
        };
        let desc=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(History.prototype);
        delete desc.constructor;
        Object.defineProperties(History.prototype,{

            replaceState:Object.assign({},desc.replaceState,{
                value:function(state,title,url){
                    let params={state,title,url};
                    HistoryNavigation.dispatchEvent('history.state.replace',params);
                    params=Object.assign({state,title,url},params);
                    params=listenerReplaceState(params);
                    desc.replaceState.value.call(this,params.state,params.title,params.url);
                }
            }),
            pushState:Object.assign({},desc.pushState,{
                value:function(state,title,url){
                    let params={state,title,url};
                    HistoryNavigation.dispatchEvent('history.state.push',params);
                    params=Object.assign({state,title,url},params);
                    params=listenerPushState(params);
                    return desc.pushState.value.call(this, params.state, params.title, params.url);
                }
            })
        });
        HistoryNavigation.addEventListener('popstate',function(event){
            let HNState;
            if(event.state==null){
                HNState=init_HNState;
            } else {
                HNState=event.state.HNState;
            }
            let key_prev=history_stack.indexOf(current_state.timestamp);
            let key_state=history_stack.indexOf(HNState.timestamp);
            let delta=key_state-key_prev;
            let params={delta,event,state:Object.assign({},event.state)};
            delete params.state.HNState;
            HNState.history_stack=history_stack;
            if(event.state!==null){
                event.state.HNState=HNState;
            }
            current_state=HNState;
            HistoryNavigation.dispatchEvent('history.go',params);
        });

    }
    static addEventListener(...arg)
    {
        window.addEventListener(...arg);
    }
    static removeEventListener(...arg)
    {
        window.removeEventListener(...arg);
    }
    static dispatchEvent(event,params)
    {
        if(!(event instanceof Event)){
            event=new Event(event,{cancelable:true});
        }
        event.params=params;
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    };
}
HistoryNavigation.init();

// exemple

HistoryNavigation.addEventListener('popstate',function(event){
    console.log('Will not start because they blocked the work');
});
HistoryNavigation.addEventListener('history.go',function(event){
    event.params.event.stopImmediatePropagation();// blocked popstate listeners
    console.log(event.params);
    // back or forward - see event.params.delta

});
HistoryNavigation.addEventListener('history.state.push',function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
HistoryNavigation.addEventListener('history.state.replace',function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
history.pushState({h:'hello'},'','');
history.pushState({h:'hello2'},'','');
history.pushState({h:'hello3'},'','');
history.back();

    ```
````

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks for adding to this (I still find it amazing that there's conversation on this thread after so many years)

Comment: This appears to be a clever history tracking mechanism.  However, the code is uncommented, so it's pretty difficult to follow.  If someone navigates away from the current page, the code won't detect that button press, which doesn't answer the original question of "How do you definitively detect whether or not the user has pressed the back button in the browser?"  Button presses and history tracking are two different things even though one may trigger the other.  The fact there's still conversation indicates a major flaw in web browser design.

Comment: CubicleSoft, Let’s imagine that there is an actual transition (a page formed directly when the link is clicked) and a virtual transition (a page generated by the event, while there is no real click through). In the actual transition, (if the domains are different during the transition), the browser does not allow you to track the transitions due to security policies and privacy. With a dynamic transition, your code is executed in the context of your actions, you have the opportunity to track the actions in the navigation panel. At the very least, this is satisfactory for your SPA application.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take at it. The assumption is, when the URL changes but there has no click within the `document` detected, it's a browser back (yes, or forward). A users click is reset after 2 seconds to make this work on pages that load content via Ajax:

```
(function(window, $) {
  var anyClick, consoleLog, debug, delay;
  delay = function(sec, func) {
    return setTimeout(func, sec * 1000);
  };
  debug = true;
  anyClick = false;
  consoleLog = function(type, message) {
    if (debug) {
      return console[type](message);
    }
  };
  $(window.document).click(function() {
    anyClick = true;
    consoleLog("info", "clicked");
    return delay(2, function() {
      consoleLog("info", "reset click state");
      return anyClick = false;
    });
  });
  return window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    if (anyClick !== true) {
      consoleLog("info", "Back clicked");
      return window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'analyticsEvent',
        eventCategory: 'test',
        eventAction: 'test'
      });
    }
  });
})(window, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

The document.mouseover does not work for IE and FireFox.
However I have tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    var $sample = $("body");
    if ($sample.is(":hover")) {
      window.innerDocClick = true;
    } else {
      window.innerDocClick = false;
    }
  });

});

window.onhashchange = function () {
  if (window.innerDocClick) {
    //Your own in-page mechanism triggered the hash change
  } else {
    //Browser back or forward button was pressed
  }
};
```

This works for Chrome and IE and not FireFox. Still working to get FireFox right. Any easy way on detecting Browser back/forward button click are welcome, not particularly in JQuery but also AngularJS or plain Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of a sidemenu that can be closed using the back button.
Works on Chrome/Edge/Android/...

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
    .sidebarMenu {
        height: 25%;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        width: 25%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
        background-color: #aaa;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .openSidebarMenu {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: none;
    }

    .openSidebarMenu:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu" onclick="sidemenu()">
<label for="openSidebarMenu">
Menu (click me or back button to close)
</label>
<div id="sidebarMenu" class="sidebarMenu" onclick="sideBarClose()">
    <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    function sidemenu() {
        var selection = document.getElementById("openSidebarMenu");
        if (selection.checked) {
            window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "");
            checked = true;
            window.onpopstate = function(event) {
                var selection = document.getElementById("openSidebarMenu");
                if(event && selection.checked) {
                    selection.checked = false;
                    console.log("event 1");

                } else {
                    console.log("event 2");
                }
            }
        } else {
            history.back();
        }
    }
    
    function sideBarClose() {
        var selection = document.getElementById("openSidebarMenu");
        if (selection.checked) {
            selection.checked = false;
            history.back();
        }
    }   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by keeping track of the original event that triggered the `hashchange` (be it a swipe, a click or a wheel), so that the event wouldn't be mistaken for a simple landing-on-page, and using an additional flag in each of my event bindings. The browser won't set the flag again to `false` when hitting the back button:

```
var evt = null,
canGoBackToThePast = true;

$('#next-slide').on('click touch', function(e) {
    evt = e;
    canGobackToThePast = false;
    // your logic (remember to set the 'canGoBackToThePast' flag back to 'true' at the end of it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input style="display:none" id="__pageLoaded" value=""/>


 $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#__pageLoaded").val() != 1) {

            $("#__pageLoaded").val(1);


        } else {
            shared.isBackLoad = true;
            $("#__pageLoaded").val(1);  

            // Call any function that handles your back event

        }
    });
```

The above code worked for me. On mobile browsers, when the user clicked on the back button, we wanted to restore the page state as per his previous visit.

Comment: Above code worked for me , on mobile browsers, when users clicked on back button , we wanted to restore the page state as per his previous visit

Comment: There's no reason to store the state in the DOM. Nor should you be requerying the DOM for the input and it should be stored as a local variable. If you don't want an `<input>` to be displayed, use `<input type="hidden">`. If you wanted to use this approach, a variable on the `window` would be preferred, but even that isn't wise.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Kotlin/JS (React):

```
import org.w3c.dom.events.Event
import kotlin.browser.document
import kotlin.browser.window

...
override fun componentDidMount() {
    window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href)
    window.addEventListener("popstate", actionHandler)
}
...
val actionHandler: (Event?) -> Unit = {
    window.history.pushState(
        null,
        document.title,
        window.location.href
    )
    // add your actions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a solution for this issue and put together a simple skeleton test html based on a few answers here and the MDN Web Doc pages for [`History.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and [`WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

The following HTML and JavaScript is easy enough to copy and paste and test.

Works with back and forward browser buttons, shortcut keys, adds a change to the URL (which is important in some cases).

Simply enough to add to existing code key points and should be expandable too.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="p1">Option 1</div>
<div id="p2">Option 2</div>
<div id="p3">Option 3</div>
<div id="p4">Option 4</div>
<div id="c"></div>
<script>
var chg={
    set:function(str){
        var d=document.getElementById("c");
        d.textContent=str;
    },
    go:function(e){
        var s={"p":this.id};
        chg.set(s.p);
        hstry.add(s);
    }
};
var hstry={
    add:function(s){
        var u=new URL(window.location);
        u.searchParams.set("x",s.p);
        window.history.pushState(s,"",u);
    },
    adjust:function(state){
        if(state.p){
            chg.set(state.p);
        }
    }
};
window.onpopstate=function(e){
    console.log("popstate, e.state:["+ JSON.stringify(e.state) +"]");
    hstry.adjust(e.state);
}
window.onload=function(){
    var i,d,a=["p1","p2","p3","p4"];
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        d=document.getElementById(a[i]);
        d.addEventListener("click",chg.go,false);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

browser will emit `popstate` event if you navigate through your app with calling

```
window.history.pushState({},'','/to')
```

If you manually enter the addresses into the address bar and click on the back button, `popstate` event will NOT be fired.

If you navigate in your app with this simplified function

```
const navigate = (to) => {
    window.history.pushState({}, ",", to);
  };
```

then this will work

```
const handlePopstate = () => {
  console.log("popped");
};
window.addEventListener("popstate", handlePopstate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best solution I was able to find :

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (window.PerformanceNavigationTiming) {
            const navigationEntries = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation');
            if (navigationEntries.length > 0) {
                var navigationEntryType = navigationEntries[0].type;
                if (navigationEntryType === 'back_forward') {
                    alert("back_forward triggered")
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

### None of the answers here really 100% answer the specific Q (All Answers detects back -or- forward `not` only "back").

#### popstate event "Problem" (Fires both on back/forward)

`popstate` event of the Window interface is fired when the active **history entry changes** while the user navigates the session history.

`history entry changes` both in "**back**" and "**forward**" button events (So none of the answers above really dedect only "back" button).

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
  console.log('User clicked back button -or- forward button
 -or- history entry changes by any other trigger');
});
```

**The solution?** True to october 23 the API missing this idea. **Shitty like Hell** (No "simple solution").

Related issue (Also without real/clean solution):
[How do I retrieve if the popstate event comes from back or forward actions with the HTML5 pushstate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255/how-do-i-retrieve-if-the-popstate-event-comes-from-back-or-forward-actions-with)

Answer (score -39):

I tried the above options but none of them is working for me. Here is the solution

```
if(window.event)
   {
        if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)
        {
            alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
    }
```

Refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696526/Solution-to-Browser-Back-Button-Click-Event-Handli for more details

Comment: @MunamYousuf It's pretty obvious why this piece of code doesn't really work. It tracks the back button of the browser but the button is outside the viewport, hence the coordinates clientX and clientY should not be obtainable. Assuming it works, how about iOS? The back button is at the bottom... Also the way it is written is super inefficient, it is a conditional for every single event triggered... God it's so bad that am going to give it a down vote.

Comment: This is horrendous! why would you do such thing? :/ and it won't even work as James said.

Comment: this is funny AF, tho XD