# How to manipulate history with history.go?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function del_cookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Spanish Chat, Child Abuse Chat, Child Abuse Support, Child Abuse Discussion, Suvivor, chat, discussion, support, domestic violence, violencia domestica, abuso infantil, abuso de niño">
  <meta name="description" content="Moderated chat rooms for victims and survivors of child abuse and domestic violence.">
  <title>Yes ICAN: International Child Advocacy Network</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

       <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("SAFETY ALERT: If you are in danger, please use a safer computer, or call 911, your local hotline, or the U.S. National Domestic Violence Hotline at 1-800-799-7233 and TTY 1-800-787-3224. See more technology safety tips online.")
    </script>-->

  </head>
  <body onLoad="initialize();">
    <div id="wrapper">
     <!--Main Navigation Bar-->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="site logo" id="navlogo" src="img/logo_short_sm.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Home page" target="_blank" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Group Facilitated Chat Room" href="gethelp.html">Get Help</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message Board Community" href="community-rules.html">Community Forums</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Learn More About Abuse" href="aboutabuse.html">About Abuse</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Learn More About YesICAN" href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Opportunities to volunteer, donate, and get involved!" href="get-involved.html">Get Involved</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!--Right side of navigation bar-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <div class="btn btn-lg btn-danger donate-nav"><a target="_blank" href="https://donatenow.networkforgood.org/yesican?code=Homepage">Donate <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav><!--END NAVIGATION-->
    <img id="banner" alt="home page banner" src="img/banner.jpg"/>
    <div id="content">
      <section class="col-md-8"><!--Left column content goes here-->
       <h2>Our Mission<small><br>Working World Wide to Stop the Silence and Cycle of Abuse</small></h2>
       <p>The International Child Advocacy Network, Inc. (YesICAN) is a leading global provider of online information for those who have issues around child abuse. It is our mission to work worldwide to break the silence and cycle of abuse. <strong><em>We</em> believe</strong> that child abuse could cease to exist if everyone had the capability to receive accurate, up-to-date information about abuse and then had the capacity to receive assistance and support to change.</p>
       <h2>How We Make a Difference</h2>
       <p>Our website provides information, statistics, and definitions of abuse. We also have the <a href="community-rules.html"><em>Yes</em>ICAN Community</a> where individuals who have questions regarding child abuse and domestic violence can join with others to discuss various concerns and ideas around these topics.</p>
       <p>The premier service of our organization is our <a href="chat-schedule.html">facilitated chat</a> groups.  <strong>In these groups we offer an opportunity for abused children and adults to speak with others and to get council and support from trained facilitators.</strong>  These facilitators have gone through a 60-hour training lead by a Licensed Therapist.  To date, we have had over 44,000 participants in our chat rooms.  We run specialized chat groups for teens, adult-survivors, victims of domestic violence, individuals who are in close relationship with abuse survivors and parents.</p>
       <h2>Our Current Focus</h2>
       <p>Our focus for now, is the development of an on-line parenting program.  In this 6-8 week program, individuals will receive training in non-violent parenting.  This training will include dynamics of both physical and emotional development, and appropriate discipline.  In addition, each member of the program will have access to support groups where the topic of each weeks' training session will be discussed.  During this time specific issues and concerns that come up for each participant will be shared in a safe and supportive environment.</p> 
       <p>It is our hope that in the future, we will provide an international support forum, specifically targeting military personnel and their dependents that are based outside of the United States.</p>
     </section>
     <section class="col-md-4" style="border-left:1px solid #cfd1d4;"><!--Right column content goes here-->
       <div class="well">
        <h2>April Kickstarter</h2>
        <a href="https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/unbrokenangels/unbroken-angels" target="_blank"><img src="img/unbrokenkickstarterbutton.png"/></a>
        <p>Please support and <a href="fundraiser.html">learn more about</a> our kickstarter running through this April!</p>
      </div>
      <h2>In Memorial</h2>
      <a href="memorial.html"><img alt="Memorial List" src="img/memorial_list.jpg"/></a>
      <p>We keep <a href="memorial.html">this list in honor of the children</a> who have died from the injuries infliected upon them as a result of child abuse.</p>

      <h2>Missing Children<br><small>Alert Cases</small></h2>
      <section style="border: #cfd1d4 solid 1px; border-radius:2%; padding:10px;">
       <!-- start feedwind code --><script type="text/javascript">document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "http://www.missingkids.com/missingkids/servlet/XmlServlet?act=rss&LanguageCountry=en_US&orgPrefix=NCMC",rssmikle_frame_width: "100%",rssmikle_frame_height: "400",frame_height_by_article: "0",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "off",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "2",mcspeed: "20",sort: "Off",rssmikle_title: "off",rssmikle_title_sentence: "",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#FF0000",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "off",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script><div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:300px;"><a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a><!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.--></div><!-- end feedwind code --></section>

     </section>

   </div>

   <div class="container"  style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#d3d3d3">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Safety Warning</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">       
            <p style="text-align:center"> Your computer can be monitored by others. For your safety, consider using a public computer or a friend’s computer. If you are in danger, please call 911, your local hotline, or the U.S. National Domestic Violence Hotline at<a href="tel:+1.800.799.7233" class="call" onClick="return probablyPhone;"> +1-800-799-7233</a> and <br> TTY <a href="tel:+1.800.787.3224" class="call" onClick="return probablyPhone;">+1-800-787-3224</a>.</p>
            <p style="text-align:center"> To learn more how to computer safety, click the following link: <br><a href="internet-safety-tips.html">Internet Safety Tips</a></br></p>
            <!--Wording can be better just for the meantime-->
            <p style="text-align:center"> If you are not safe, click the following button: <br><span class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="get-away" id="del_cookie">Escape Button</span></br></p>  
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <p class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-default" class="btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--End of Modal container-->
          <!--<div class="container">

                <section class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="list-group" id="sidebar">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                      Link 1
                    </a>
                  </div>
              </section>
            </div>-->
          </div><!--End wrapper-->

          <footer>
            <div id="footer-right">

              <ul>
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <li>SUPPORT OUR CAUSE</li>
                <li><a href="https://donatenow.networkforgood.org/yesican?code=Homepage" target="_blank">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
                <li><a href="fundraiser.html">Fundraising Events</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <li>FOLLOW US</li>
                <li>
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://ww.facebook.com/yesicanorg"><img src="img/social/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.instagram.com/childadvocacynetwork"><img src="img/social/instagram-icon.png" alt="Instagram Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/YesICANorg"><img src="img/social/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com/Yesicanorg"><img src="img/social/pinterest-icon.png" alt="Pinterest Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/childadvocacynetwork"><img src="img/social/youtube-icon.png" alt="YouTube Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="footer-left">
              <p id="footer-slogan">BREAK THE <strong>SILENCE</strong> <br>AND <strong>CYCLE</strong> OF ABUSE</p>
              <p id="copyright">Copyright&copy; 2015 International Child Advocacy Network</p>
            </div>
          </footer>
          <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
          <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
          <script src="js/escape-button.js"></script>
          <script src="js/history.replace.js"></script>              

          <!--Testing to see if it works-->
    <!--<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
                     $('#myModal').modal('show');
                     $.cookie('pop', '1');
                  }

             });
           </script>-->

           <!--Works fine-->
           <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
              $( '#myModal' ).modal('show');
            });
          </script>

          <script>
            var probablyPhone = ((/iphone|android|ie|blackberry|fennec/).test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
            function initialize() {
              ( function( $ ) { 
                $( '.call' ).css ( "text-decoration", "none" );
                $( '.call' ).css ( "color", "black" );
                $( '.call' ).css ( "cursor", "default" );     
              } )( jQuery );
            }
          </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

I am doing a website for abuse survivors and I have created a escape button that will jump the user to another link and replace the location of the site with another site like google. I am currently trying to figure out how to manipulate the history back button. Currently, I have this code but it is not working at all when the back button or back arrow is clicked on. Also, what would be the best approach to replace/erase the cookies when the user visits the website.

```js
function getAway() {
  // Get away right now
  window.open("http://weather.com", "_newtab");
  // Replace current site with another benign site
  window.location.replace('http://google.com');
  // This should clear all back button history.
  var Backlen = history.length;
  history.go(-2);
}

$(function() {

  $("#get-away").on("click", function(e) {
    getAway();
  });

  $("#get-away a").on("click", function(e) {
    // allow the (?) link to work
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

Comment: can you please provide your html snippet.

Comment: I have added the html file, thank you for your help

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser