# Detect browser back button with Hashtag in url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with detecting the browser back button event. I managed to call script when back-button is clicked, but the problem lies in the hashtag.

The script works when the url doesn't contain a hashtag. However when the hashtag character is in the url, the script automatically fires even if the back button wasn't clicked.

```
window.onload = function () {             
  if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
      history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
      alert(' It Works !')
    };
  } else {
    var ignoreHashChange = true;
    window.onhashchange = function () {
      if (!ignoreHashChange) {
        ignoreHashChange = true;
        window.location.hash = Math.random();
        alert('else!');
      } else {
        alert('else in else!');
        ignoreHashChange = false;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

How can I modify the script to run only when the back button is clicked?

Comment: You can use this plugin - https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange and then have an event like window.onhashchange to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: I tried both, but it still fire everytime the hashtag changes