# Intercept or catch a chrome click event on the interface

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is possible to intercept a click event on the chrome interface? I mean, not in the page that I'm visiting, but a click on a tab or a click on the "go back button", a click on the print button in the settings menu or a click on the "show all favourites button", ECC...
I cannot find anything useful in the APIs documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be no, you can't directly detect the 'physical' button clicking event.

On the other side, you can listen to the request sent from the button. For example, when 'go back button' is clicked, it usually means the browser history is back, and you may refer [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) for more info.

Please be aware that those methods may be tricky and may not be supported by every browser.