# Redirect user to another page when they click the browser Back button on the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Our site has an issue where the browser back button is not returning you to the page you navigated from. Specifically, this occurs when you click a link to navigate to our home page and the browser back button is then not working. We need a temporary fix to this problem until we can correctly resolve this issue. 
So, is it possible to have some jquery or javascript that does the following:
If a user is on a specific page (for example, *www.abc.com/index.htm*), and the user clicks the browser back button, force the browser to display the page *www.xyz.com*?

I am not a software developer so my knowledge of coding is fairly rudimentary and I do know that changing the default behavior of the browser back button is not good practice.

Comment: What you're wanting isn't really possible.  It may work in one browser, work differently in another browser and not work at all in a third.  You want to fix the issue with the site and the links, there is no proper shortcut in this regard.  If your links are taking you to anchor tags (think table of contents) then the back button will scroll the page if not then the back button will take you to the last loaded page, so if you're using a bunch of sliding animations when you click stuff to move content your back button will ignore this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)