# iframe: How to reload only the iframe's content when the browser's reload button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this iframe which link to another page

```
<iframe height="80%" width="100%" src="index.php" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

<p> .... Page .... </p>
```

How do I make the `iframe` reload when we click on reflesh[image] button of the browser

Comment: you need to use `ajax` , i think

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to override the refresh button's behaviour at JS level.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser But I am with @RoryMcCrossan, I don't think that it's possible to prevent the default action of a browser button.