# pop current view twice from navigation

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have four pages in hierarchy, 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 and I am navigating to them with `this.router.navigate(..)`.

Is there a way, how to get from view (3) directly to view (1)? Calling `this.location.back();` twice shows for while page (2), which I do not want to.

Can I pop it directly or navigate to page (1) while keeping (0) still on stack?

Edit:
I need to be it working primary on Android/iOS.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [skipLocationChange](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html#!#skipLocationChange-anchor) parameter of `routerLink` or [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#skipLocationChange-anchor) does what you want.

```ts
this.router.navigate('some route', 
    { navigationExtras: { skipLocationChange: true}})
```

This way the navigation from 1 to 2 or 2 to 3 doesn't add a history entry and navigating back from 3 directly results in going back to 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep 2 on stack for case of returnin there from another page e.g.  2 -> 4.

Comment: Don't see a way to accomplish that.

Comment: TY, knowing that st. is not possible is answer too.

Comment: Perhaps listening for back navigation and then navigate back again by code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: I don't think this answer will work for NativeScript routes.

Comment: @OtacilioOliveiraLimaNeto any reason why? I don't know NativeScript.

Comment: I think `skipLocationChange` is not supported on NativeScript routing yet.