# Method call on browser back button not forward

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function on back button click, I am using the below code which is working on both forward and back button but I want only back button click.
Not be able to differentiate between Back and Forward click.

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      alert('Back button was pressed.');
    });

  }
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) has some useful tips. Take a look.

Comment: Not working mention solution in attached link. Methods  all are working in both forward and back click.