# Flash message shows after clicking, go back and go forward browser button

Tags: php, laravel, flash-message

I have shown flash message once request is received from the server. If a users click go back and go forward button simultaneously... He again sees the same flash message which I think it's a bad message to the users... How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Simultaneously clicking back and forward is not possible. I suppose you mean: First back and than forward.

Comment: here's a reference https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22585#issuecomment-354620188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this problem using follwing code

```
  <script>
   @if(!empty(Session::get('message')))
    var popupId = "{{ uniqid() }}";
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem('shown-' + popupId)) {
        swal({
            html:
            "{{Session::get('message')}}",
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            animation: false,
            customClass: 'animated tada',
            focusConfirm: false,
            background: '#008eb0'
        });
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('shown-' + popupId, '1');
    @endif
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because Browser helps you to load the page with the cache. You can do these

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, private, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, max-stale = 0', false);
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

or

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('status') }} status-box">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but the proposed header solutions above didn't work for me.

Instead, I use [performance.getEntriesByType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) (which is widely supported) to determine if the user arrived on the page via the back button and, if so, I remove the code which displays the flash message from the flash message container:

```
<script>
        var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
        for (var i = 0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
            if(perfEntries[i].type === "back_forward"){ // if user has reach the page via the back button...
                document.querySelector("#flashMessageContainer").innerHTML = ""; //...delete the contents of the flash container
            }
        }
</script>
```

'performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")' returns "back_forward" if the user has arrived on the page by clicking either the back, or the forward, browser button (in my case, a flash message isn't necessary on a forward click either). It returns "navigate" if a link was clicked or a form submission resulted in a redirect.

Attribution: I pinched [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56653850/11592072) from llaaalu

Answer (score 1):

You could store the messageId from the shown message in a variable or in an (hidden) input-field with JavaScript, so you could check if the message has allready be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

İf success cache delete

```
@if (\Session::has('danger'))
<script>
    iziToast.show({
        title: 'Başarısız',
        message: "{!! \Session::get('danger') !!}",
        color: 'red',
        position: 'topRight', // bottomRight, bottomLeft, topRight, topLeft, topCenter, bottomCenter, center
        timeout: 3000,

    });
</script>

@php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
@endphp
```

@endif