# how to completely logout in laravel 5.5 controller?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

After I logout of my laravel application, in the browser I press the button to backward (go back) and then I see the dashboard.

I want to eliminate this "session" that laravel mantein if I go back.

can anyone help me?

EDIT: I have two login files, one is inside the Controllers/Auth and another is inside the Controller/. I'm sure this is not a good practice, but it's keeping my system up and running. how to solve this?

Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Session;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    private $user;

}
```

my Login Controllers/LoginController.php ->

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Session;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    private $user;


    public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        \Session::flash('success',"logout");
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

}
```

my DashboardController ->

```
use App\Authorization;
use App\BackLog;
use App\Key;
use App\isKeyInUse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {

        return view('dashboard');
    }


}
```

my web.php ->

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/dashboard/getKey', 'DashboardController@getKey')->name('dashboard.key')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Show your dashboard controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because caching. to prevent that we can create a [**`middleware`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) that intercepts every request and set the `cache` to expire in`0` time and thus it will force the page to reload when the user press the back button here's the steps to create the middleware :

### first

create a middleware i will call it `MyAuth`:

```
php artisan make:middleware MyAuth
```

### second

register the middleware in `app/Http/kernel.php`

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
      ...,
      'my_auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyAuth::class,
   ];
```

### third

in the newly created middleware `app/Http/Middleware/MyAuth.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
         $response =  $next($request);   
         return $response
                ->withHeaders([
                    'Cache-Control' => 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
                    'Pragma'=> 'no-cache',
                    'Expires' => '0'
                ]);
        }
  }
```

### Then

you can add your middleware like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'my_auth'], function() {
  
  // All your routes you want to be secure

});
```

This code has been derived from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLkA1g2s65U)

Comment: I like your suggestion, but the name `MyAuth` for a cache control middleware is a bit confusing. You may wanna adjust it.

Comment: thank you friend, it is because of this that I love stackoverflow <3

Comment: @Namoshek I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

> You are missing Request in logout function

```
    public function logout(Request $request){
        Auth::logout();
        \Session::flash('success',"logout");
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
```

> And write in your dashboard controller

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Now Show your Logout file and Dashboard controller screen shot

Comment: https://imgur.com/3b52Voh
I do not have the logout file, I only use the logout function in my login file

Comment: Also show your file in which logout function is written

Answer (score 0):

Insert these lines to your Dashboard controller and then check:

```
public function __contruct() 
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This will check user is logged in or not? If user is loggedout, then it send to specific login page as you defined in auth middleware.

Comment: Can you share your dashboard controller and routes file?

Comment: I shared my dashboard and routes

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the Back button of your browser will load the previously loaded document. It is just visible but will not work for sure. For this you just have to override back press event from javascript.

See link [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 7.x, you can logout from the controller by using the following command:

```
Auth::logout()
```