# Is it possible to set time out for Back-Forward cache in browser?

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, browser, browser-cache

I'm trying to invalidate browser cache after 1 hour.
In response header I have tried to add the following parameters.

`Cache-Control:max-age=3600`

Its working when I'm reloading the page or refreshing the page. But when using the back/forward button in browser it still loading from the browser. *Is there any way /suggetsion to resolve this?*

NB: *When [I googled it most the articles suggesting to use `no-store` parameter in `Cache-Control`.](https://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history) But at that time it will not use the browser cache all the time. And I need to use browser cache for first 1 hour after loading the page. After that it should load from server.*

Comment: You could try the _Expires_ header but you want to do something that is not a recommended use of the browser history. Read [RFC 2616 13.13 History Lists](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) to understand why _Cache-Control_ is not doing what you expected.

Comment: Thanks @EugèneAdell
I went through that document. I hope that there is no direct way to achieve this in browser :)

Comment: Have a look at this question [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25806608/7748072) which talks about using JavaScript to track events particularly the _history back_. I believe this would override the default browser behavior, and then your _Cache-Control_ setting would be applied. Keep us informed if this worked.