# How to prevent browser from ‘back button’ when file upload is initiated by iframe and parent page has been routed using html5-history API?

Tags: iframe, vuejs2, onbeforeunload, pushstate, html5-history

I have an iframe (implemented using vuejs) inside a parent page (a .net C# page).
iframe has a file upload feature and user can press back button (or refresh) while upload is in progress. Parent page has implemented html5-history API.

**My goal** is to prevent browser to go back, on user action (showing the alert popup - the one is generated by beforeunload event)

DETAILS: refresh works as expected, because this emits beforeunload event.
but back button does not emit beforeunload event. (because page was not opened directly, instead pushState was used.)

I **expect** that user has some way to 'not leave' page when upload is interrupted by browser-back button. (what **is happening** now?)But user is able to just go back and upload is aborted without any alert.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this sees to apply: [how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Thanks @djhallx, and yes this is the same solution I found.

Comment: I don't understand... Is it solved ?

Comment: @filipe yes it's solved.