# Is it possible to detect hardware back button click event on android device by js?

Tags: javascript, vue-router, html5-history

Can I detect click event when user press hardware back button (button on mobile context menu) using js?

For example, I have two pages:

- Login
- Homepage

The homepage has a popup window, currently, when the popup is showing and then user press the back button, browser will be back to login page.
But I just want browser close the popup instead of go back to login page in this case.

Is it possible to detect it?

**Edit**: This question is about the hardware back button on mobile device (android), not the browser back button.

Comment: You may make a special query for the page with the popup, something like `/home?popup=true` and redirect from `home` to `home?popup=true` on popup appear, so clicking back button will make you go back to `home`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Hi @AdeelImran, i tried it before create this question, but they discussed about browser back button, i asked about hardware back button on mobile device.

Comment: @Igor but it will reload homepage, right? can i close popup without reload anything?

Comment: @Hung Nguyen yes, you should just do `$router.push({ query: { popup: true } }` on popup show and browser back button will return you back to `home` route without page reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct anwser that I got from @Igor:

> you should just do $router.push({ query: { popup: true } } on popup show and browser back button will return you back to home route without page reloading