# Show alert when click on browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a message when the user clicks on browser back button. For that, I have used below lines of code and its working fine in IE and Firefox browser.In chrome the below code is not working until I click on anywhere on window. Without clicking anywhere on window then if I click on the back button then it is going back.
Anyone solution will help.

```
    history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        ShowAlert('Back button functionality is disabled.', 'Error', 20);
            history.go(1);
     };
```

Comment: Did you tried this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: Yes.not working.

Comment: I think that nothing you can do about this, this is probably some security or abuse prevention feature.