# How to detect the event triggered when User clicks on Browser back button

Tags: javascript, html

I came across a requirement of performing some button click action when a user clicks on browser back button,

I tried using `window.onpopstate(),` but the issue here is, `it is triggering when the page loads, when user clicks on browser back and when user clicks on browser forward`...

I want to catch the exact event only when the user clicks on Browser Back button...
My intention of solving this issue is:

inside the browser back event I would like to find a back button and make a click function which would achieve my task.. as below:

```
$('input[name="back"]').click();
```

So my problem here is to detect the Browser back button event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: I have gone through the above solutions none of them are working