# Catch event of back button in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to catch event when user click on back button in browser using javascript.
And can I prevent returning to the previous page when click on back button?
Anyone can help me plz.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: you can use window.history.back() to go back page