# Browser Back button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help browser back button click event.
After clicking back button on browser, display a confirmation box, but before clicking ok button , page just refreshes.

Comment: That [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) will help you I guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)