# How to Detect Browser back button click, which is compatible for all browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried below codes but that is not consistent.

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 2) {
    alert("Back button clicked");
}
```

and,

```
if (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === 'back_forward') {
   alert("Back button clicked");
}
```

**Please suggest if any other possible ways to Detect back button in browsers.**

Comment: Have you tried `history.back()`? might do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Your question asks about *trigger* back (ie raise/cause the browser to go back) but both your samples about about *detecting* back - which are you trying to do?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes my question is about detecting the back button click in browsers. I updated the Title.

Answer (score 0):

Try history

(function() {

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
  
      alert('Back button was pressed.');
    });
}
```

})();

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in this above condition, on click of back button in browser it doesn't enter the 'popstate' function.