# How to clear data using a button? LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Scenario: My website does shoe orders. When a user proceeds into buying a shoe, it goes to pending orders. My problem is that when the user presses the back button of the browser, the order data is loaded and still be available to be purchased and proceed to pending orders.

Is there a way that I can make the back button of the browser to erase the order details after proceeding to pending orders?

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) answer - that should do the trick, **BUT** it's quite common that if you add goods to the cart, it stays there and it doesn't matter if you pressed the *back* button or not.

So, is it really necessary to catch this scenario? Is it causing any problem? If so, I would personally use a cron job to remove unpain pending orders (in the last X hours)