# do something when click on window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, history

i want to do something when the user **click** on window.hostory.back()
Is there such a thing?
Would appreciate help!

like:

```
$(document).on('click', window.history.back(), function () {//guest what?})
```

**update**

in the screen u have link:

```
<a class="Active" href="whatEver">
```

and this script:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Active", ShowModal);
```

When I return to the previous page, (click on the browser arrow) the model is displayed again and does not disappear. What to do to hide it?

Comment: Why do you want to change the default behaviour of the back button?

Comment: This is not a thing. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish so that people can help.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: There are no such things, maybe you want to trigger something when the user is back to some page so you can manage through query append in URL

Comment: i'm added more information