# Prevent page refresh when browser back button hits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I need to prevent page refresh when back button clicks in my wordpress application. I tried some solutions available online, but no use.

Here is my code in `functions.php`

```
<script>
    console.log(123)
    $(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
       console.log("pop");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
   //blah blah blah
}
```

You can use this for more info read this answer [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

or you can use this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost."; };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pageshow](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/jquerymobile/event_pageshow.asp.html) event to handle browser navigation through your page history

Use this code may it's Works for you

```
window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
  var pageHistory = event.persisted || 
                         ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && 
                              window.performance.navigation.type === 2 );
  if ( pageHistory ) {
    // Handle page restore.
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```