# React - beforeunload event listener on pressing browser back button

Tags: reactjs, web, browser, onbeforeunload

I have a React application with a form component.

When a user fills in the form and tries to navigate away from the page in any way (closing tab, closing browser, refreshing page, pressing browser back button or any other navigation), I want to alert the user of unsaved changes.

I did the following -

```
useEffect(() => {
    // do something

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = "";
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = "";
      });
    };
  }, []);
```

This works when I try to close the browser, close tab or refersh the page. But when I press back button, I do not get any alert.

Is it that I cannot capture that back event due to security reasons? (FYI I am using Brave browser).
If I can, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to subscribe to **onhashchange** event.

Here is thread with a similar query:

[How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)