# Disable button back of browser

Tags: javascript

I tried doing it this way but it takes interaction with the screen for it to work, is there any way to make it work without interaction

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    history.back();
    history.forward();
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
    };
```

Comment: I think this is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: I don't think it's possible and I also think that it shouldn't be possible because it's horrible UX

Answer (score 0):

do you mean disable back button of a browser?

`window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);`

`window.onpopstate = function () { window.history.go(1); };`

Comment: i tried running in browser console it works, but running in text editor code it needs to interact with the screen to work

Comment: is the window or document already loaded ?

Comment: without interact the screen , You mean by keyboard or mouse button to trigger the back button?

Comment: Or actually you mean online code editor

Comment: I mean click or press any button on the screen

Comment: no, I use VS code

Comment: you can put these code everywhere , not only button .

Comment: if you are using react , please check if the window or document already loaded before 
execute the code , you can check console for error msg if it call before windows load