# GA4 - Back Button Vs. <-Back Link

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to track the number of times a user taps/clicks the <- Back Link compared to users who use native browser Back Button.

I'm fairly new to Google Analytics, and GTM.  I'm using React.

My thoughts are

- Use GTM Triggers mostly to "listen" for click events
  OR
- Use coded click event handlers in react.

How would I know a user clicks the Browsers back button?
AND
How would I link the events together for comparison?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0):

[How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser) This goes through back navigation listening. You can use both GTM and React to accomplish it. There are multiple of methods described.