# How to implement Facebook like history.pushState system

Tags: browser-history, html5-history

I have 3 related questions to ask

### Question 1

On a `window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e)`, how do I know if the button that was pressed was the `forward()` or `back()` button. For example

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
    var buttonDirection = // the button that was clicked
    if(buttonDirection == history.back()){
        // blah blah blah
    } else if(buttonDirection == history.forward()){
        // blah blah blah
    }
})
```

### Question 2

I want to `pushState` after `ajax` success in order to change the page content so I did this, I don't really know if its the best way to do that

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path.php',
    success: function(data){
        $('html').html(data);
        history.pushState('', '', 'path.php');
        var pushed = 'yes';
    }
})
```

Now the issue is after the `ajax` success and `pushed = yes` then I want to listen to the event for when the back button is clicked to retrieve the previous page content because after the `history.pushState` the `forward()` button is disabled, so I did this

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
    if(pushed == 'yes'){
        // run code to restore back previous page content
        $.ajax({
            url: 'current_page.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('html').html(data);
                pushed = 'yesBack';
            }
        });
    }

    // now I want to run another code to replace the page content again if the forward button is clicked and pushed is == yesBack
    // that's where my reason for question 1 come out
    // so how do I know if the button that was clicked is the forward
})
```

### Final Question

If you study Facebook on mobile browsers this is what you will observe:

1. If you are on a profile picture album page and you click a photo, the `history.pushState` is fired and `ajax` request is used to change the page content which will now display the image you clicked.
2. If you click the back button the `ajax` request is used again to retrieve the previous page contents.
3. If you click the forward button again the `ajax` request is used again to change the page content to display the image once again.
4. If you continue to now scroll through the images by clicking the next or previous links and the `history.pushState` is fired again and the `ajax` request is used to retrieve the new image, no matter how much images you have scrolled, if you click the back button again it takes you back to the first page which is the profile picture album page.
5. If you then click the forward button again, it takes you to the page you left off before clicking the back button.

Now my third question is how can I achieve all these observations also in my own web page.

I tried viewing the Facebook source code but I couldn't understand it or find anywhere the `history.pushState` is triggered. Please do anyone have an answer to any of my listed questions or a document I can read to get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your first question, relating to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255/how-do-i-retrieve-if-the-popstate-event-comes-from-back-or-forward-actions-with)

You must implement it yourself which is quite easy.

- When invoking pushState give the data object a unique incrementing id (uid).
- When onpopstate handler is invoked; check the state uid against a persistent variable containing the last state uid.
- Update the persistent variable with the current state uid.
- Do different actions depending on if state uid was greater or less than last state uid.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I get the url of the page on window.popState

Comment: Thanks once again, I have figured solutions to all my questions with a clue from your answer :)