# How to detect is that back button OR forward button clicked by javascript?

Tags: javascript, back-button

Just to ensure, I am **NOT** asking how to catch back/forward button events.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
                       alert("Yahoooo!!!!"); 
                   });
```

That function above is triggered either it is browser's back button or browser's  forward button but I cannot detect which one was clicked? Was it back button or forward button?

Is there any specific event for them that I can detect it was "back" or "forward" button specifically?

**EDIT**: While I appreciate the *"duplicate question*" suggestion, the similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255/how-do-i-retrieve-if-the-popstate-event-comes-from-back-or-forward-actions-with) on stackoverflow   but the accepted answer is from January 2012!! A lot of things changed since then. Maybe there is already easier way for this!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve if the popstate event comes from back or forward actions with the HTML5 pushstate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255/how-do-i-retrieve-if-the-popstate-event-comes-from-back-or-forward-actions-with)

Comment: The accepted answer is "walk around" and 4 years old for that question!! There may be some easier way around by the time of now!

Comment: You are right, its 2012, but it is still the way to detect history navigation.

Comment: you'll have to manually keep track of some sort of index

Comment: I put some [up-to-date code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49329267/2402790) there, in case it helps.

Comment: Did you get the answer of this question?

Comment: @MartinAJ - unfortunately no.. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255/how-do-i-retrieve-if-the-popstate-event-comes-from-back-or-forward-actions-with) is the only closer suggestion but not what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and i found the answer using modern javascript.

The code is available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/comidev-france/nav.js/blob/master/nav.js)

You can detect browser back and forward button pressed in any js app that relies on popstate / pushstate using :

```
// e.detail.direction will be the "backward" or "forward" String according the pressed button 
window.addEventListener('nav::user_asked_history', function(e) {
    console.log('nav::direction=', e.detail.direction); 
})
```

You can show / hide your own in-app back and forward buttons using :

```
is_nav_forward_possible()
is_nav_backward_possible()
```

And you can also navigate around your in-app user history using

```
let nav_position;
let nav_history;
```

Have fun with modern JS !