# How to tell if the user clicked the back or forward button in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

In javascript history api, I can do something like this

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', event => {
    var data = event.state;

}, false);
```

but is there a way I can tell if the user clicked the back or forward button? Note: this is not about if they clicked one of the two, but its to distinguish which of the 2 they clicked on.

Thanks

Comment: Make a comparison between previous history entry and target location of the popstate event

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: Maybe later. All you need though is something along the lines of `history.next == history.previous ? Back pressed : Forward pressed`

Comment: @Simon Those properties aren’t likely to be accessible in most browsers.  Anyway, I posted some code in answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255), in case it helps.