# Warn web user if the back button was pressed using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi I tried to use the following javascript to warn users.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       return "Are you sure you wish to leave?";
    };
```

But I need to make sure that the back button is pressed it seems to call this when you change the url.

Thanks

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980255/how-do-i-retrieve-if-the-popstate-event-comes-from-back-or-forward-actions-with

Answer (score 1):

Try looking through [these answers here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25806608/16288497)

> So, in short, and for people that aren't necessarily using an in-page back button or an array to store the history:

```
document.onmouseover = function() {
    //User's mouse is inside the page.
    window.innerDocClick = true;
}

document.onmouseleave = function() {
    //User's mouse has left the page.
    window.innerDocClick = false;
}

window.onhashchange = function() {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
        //Your own in-page mechanism triggered the hash change
    } else {
        //Browser back button was clicked
    }
}
```

> And there you have it. a simple, three-part way to detect back button usage vs in-page elements with regards to hash navigation.

Your alert would go into the `else` section of the `window.onhashchange` handler.

Comment: I tired this when I press back on chrome the window.onhashchange is never fired. Any ideas why?

Comment: use window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event)